# Is `weekday` guaranteed to be in the range [1:7]?

Tags: ios, date, calendar, foundation

I believe the answer is yes, but Apple's documentation implies the answer is no.

> Weekday units are the numbers 1 through n, where n is the number of days in the week. For example, in the Gregorian calendar, n is 7 and Sunday is represented by 1. [weekday](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents/1410442-weekday)

That quote seems to suggest that there are alternative week lengths for different Calendar Systems.  After doing some research on Wikipedia, I couldn't find any modern calendars where `n != 7`.

Am I misreading this?  Are there any Calendars in Foundation that have weeks where `n != 7`?

Comment: Yes, `weekday` is guaranteed (at least for calendars available in iOS) to be in range, what I interpret documentation was referring to was that in different calendars weekday numbers differ. Sunday represented by 1 in Gregorian calendar, but not necessarily others.

Comment: @esesmuedgars I understood that different calendars start on different days. The wording implied that n doesn't always = 7 though.  At least to me at did.  I think, "In all calendar systems n = 7, and in the Gregorian calendar Sunday is represented by 1"  is a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a guarantee but the following code finds no calendar for any locale that doesn't have a weekday range other than `1..<8`.

```
let calIds: [Calendar.Identifier] = [ .buddhist, .chinese, .coptic, .ethiopicAmeteAlem, .ethiopicAmeteMihret, .gregorian, .hebrew, .indian, .islamic, .islamicCivil, .islamicTabular, .islamicUmmAlQura, .iso8601, .japanese, .persian, .republicOfChina]
for calId in calIds {
    var cal = Calendar(identifier: calId)
    for locId in Locale.availableIdentifiers {
        let locale = Locale(identifier: locId)
        cal.locale = locale

        if let weekdayMin = cal.minimumRange(of: .weekday), let weekdayMax = cal.maximumRange(of: .weekday) {
            if weekdayMin == weekdayMax {
                if weekdayMin.startIndex != 1 || weekdayMin.count != 7 {
                    print("Calendar \(calId) with locale \(locId) isn't 1..<8: \(weekdayMin)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Calendar \(calId) with locale \(locId) has a different min and max weekday range: \(weekdayMin) - \(weekdayMax)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Calendar \(calId) with locale \(locId) doesn't have both a min and max weekday range")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The min/max range is precisely what I needed.  I must have glossed over them when reading the docs.  After going back, I tried to use the `range(of:in:for:)`,  but oddly there is no `Component.week`.  After running your script, I'll probably just hardcode 7 or use one of the range functions.  Thanks for your help